# CasperJS to select a checkbox with specified text

Tags: javascript, checkbox, casperjs

I want to use casperJS to automatically select a checkbox

```
<tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
        <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="1" data-crdid="0005442" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Data Structures and Algorithms</td>
    <td>INT2203></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
        <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="2" data-crdid="0005682" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Machine Learning</td>
    <td>INT2204></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
        <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="3" data-crdid="003643" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Artificial Intelligence</td>
    <td>INT2205></td>
</tr>
```

The first column is the checkbox to select.
The second one is the name of the subject and the last one is the ID of the subject.

Now I just know the ID of the subject: INT2204 and I want to use casperjs to select the box of this subject. However, the only thing to distinguish is `data-crdid` which I have no clue.

Are there anyway to select the checkbox of the subject with ID 'INT2204' by casperjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve my problem without using jQuery.

Here is the HTML code which I copied from [@Evers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324960/evers) answer:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Checkbox test</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="1" data-crdid="0005442" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Data Structures and Algorithms</td>
    <td>INT2203</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="2" data-crdid="0005682" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Machine Learning</td>
    <td>INT2204</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="3" data-crdid="003643" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Artificial Intelligence</td>
    <td>INT2205</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

I will use method `getElementsInfo` and `getElementsAttribute` of CasperJS:
First, I need to collect all the data which related to the subjects. Since the only things I know is the ID and the name of the subjects, I need to know their `data-crdid` in order to select the checkbox.

```
casper.then(function () {
   // Select all the subject IDs in the table
   id = this.getElementsInfo('table tr td:nth-child(3)')
                .map(function (value, index, array) {
       return array[index].text();
   }); 

   // Select all the data-crdid in the table
   data = this.getElementsInfo('table tr td input', 'data-crdid');
});
```

After that, everything is simple. I just need to pick my subject by its ID and the `data-crdid` will have the same index in array `data`.

```
 casper.then(function () {
     selected = data[id.indexOf(subject)];
 });

 casper.thenEvaluate(function (selected) {
     document.querySelector('input[data-crdid="' + selected + '"]').click();
 }, selected);
```

Here is the full code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var subject = 'INT2204';

casper.start();
casper.thenOpen('/{{ URL }}');

casper.then(function () {
       // Select all the subject IDs in the table
       var id = this.getElementsInfo('table tr td:nth-child(3)')
                    .map(function (value, index, array) {
           return array[index].text();
       }); 

       // Select all the data-crdid in the table
       var data = this.getElementsInfo('table tr td input', 'data-crdid');

       var selected = data[id.indexOf(subject)];

       this.thenEvaluate(function (selected) {
         document.querySelector('input[data-crdid="' + selected + '"]').click();
       }, selected);
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I am trying to use your solution but it complains about the array part when selecting id's `is not a function (evaluating 'array[index].text()')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to filter on the element and get the siblings. This can be evaluated inside the page by CasperJS if you inject jQuery (if it isn't already).

Inject jQuery:

```
casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start();
casper.open('some url');
casper.then(function doSomething() {
    this.page.injectJs('relative/local/path/to/jquery.js');
     this.evaluate(function (courseId) {
        $('td').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() === courseId;
        }).siblings().find('input').prop('checked', true);
    }, 'INT2203>');
});
```

Example in Browser:

```js
var courseId = 'INT2203>';
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === courseId;
}).siblings().find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Checkbox test</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="1" data-crdid="0005442" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Data Structures and Algorithms</td>
    <td>INT2203></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="2" data-crdid="0005682" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Machine Learning</td>
    <td>INT2204></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style=" text-align:center;">
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowindex="3" data-crdid="003643" data-numcrd="3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>Artificial Intelligence</td>
    <td>INT2205></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Most of the times jQuery is already available but I'll edit my answer in case it isn't.